# Assuming a deductive theory is an ordered set of propositions, how could its order be defined mathematically ? Is it, for example, a lattice?

Tags: geometry, logic, order-theory

In this You Tube video, at 3:39   : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enZpq8jvFEs

Monsieur Phi ( understand " Monsieur Philosophie") a philosophy teacher ( and also a logician)  gives a visual presentation of Euclid's deductive system  of geometry as  an ordered set that looks like a lattice.

Is actually a deductive theory a lattice? ( It seems doubtful however, since the axioms of a theory are all minimal elements).

If not, how to caracterize formally the order of a deductive theory?

Are there different possible types of order  for deductive theories?

Is it possible for  two deductive theories to instantiate two different kinds of order?

Comment: You might be interested in [Lindenbaum–Tarski algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindenbaum%E2%80%93Tarski_algebra). It is indeed the case that the Lindenbaum–Tarski algebras for different deductive systems have different structures. Conjunction and disjunction give the meet and join operations of a lattice; this lattice is a Heyting algebra if the system is intuitionistic, and is a Boolean algebra if the system is classical. This isn't *exactly* what you're asking, though, which is why I haven't posted this as an answer.

Comment: @CliveNewstead. Thanks for this link.